# How to know if a project is spring boot or not

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pom.xml

I went through a project structure in STS where I could see a MVC pattern where controller, service,Dao , entity classes were there. But looking at pom.xml got to know that it is a web application project. But how to confirm that it is not a spring boot application..?
I m new to spring boot. All I found is there were no starter dependencies in pom.xml or any dependency has word "boot" & there was not a main method where a spring boot project starts.
So my question is which particular dependency/ parameters differentiates spring boot application from a non spring boot application ?

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:resolve` and look for anything from `org.springframework.boot`.

Answer (score 9):

In general in the first part of the pom.xml you can see this tag:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> 
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: Not mandatory. We have Spring boot application without spring-boot-starter-parent.

Answer (score 1):

Check the pom.xml. see if it includes the spring boot dependency or any other Spring boot dependency flavors like Spring-boot-starter, spring-boot-autoconfigure,spring-boot-web etc....
Basically anything with group ID

> "org.springframework.boot"

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Additionally also look for the @SpringBootApplication annotation on top of the main class.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a Gradle project, you might see something like this inside of one of your build.gradle (or [projectName].gradle) files.

```
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
```

Or maybe

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
```

The above advice to search globally for `org.springframework.boot` is sound, just wanted to stress there might not be a `pom.xml` (or any `.xml`) files present.